# Why Mobx is useful?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

MobX web tutorial is really hard to get through. Can someone explain to me in plain English why MobX is useful when React already has a state management system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mobx is a library for state management by applying functional reactive programming, it is very similar to observer pattern in OOP.

It is more convenienient, than regular react state management for components with a complex state.

- With mobx you dont need to use useState many times. you can store state in an object, that looks just like a regular js object (but is actually a proxy object, that consists of getters and setters). Instead of calling setState several times, you can change mobx state object single time.
- Mobx state object is not immutable, this is more convenient for nested state, as you don't need to create a shallow copy all the way to ensure immutability
- You can decouple some logic from the component and thus simplify it (computeds, that are similar to useMemo).
- Mobx is much more simpler, than redux, and more productive.

Here is a regular react example:

```
const Widgets = (props) => {
  const [widgets, setWidgets] = useState([])
  const [status, setStatus] = useState('loading') // loading, error, loaded

  const onLoaded = (widgets) => {
    setWidgets(widgets)
    setStatus('loaded')
  }

  
  const onClose = (widget) => {
    const index = widgets.findIndex(currWidget => widget === currWidget)
    const nextWidgets = [...widgets]
    nextWidgets[index] = { ...nextWidgets[index] }
    nextWidgets[index].status = 'animatingOut'
    setWidgets(nextWidgets)
  }

  
  const hasActiveWidgets = useMemo(() => widgets.some(widget => widget.isActive), [widgets])
  if(hasActiveToasts){
    // something
  }

  ...
}
```

Here is the same example with mobx:

```
class State {
  constructor(){
    makeAutoObservable(this) // use second parameter, to override, which properties to track and how
  }
  widgets: []
  status: 'loading'
  hasActiveWidgets: () => this.widgets.some(widget => widget.isActive)
}

const Widgets = observer((props) => {
  const state = useMemo(() => new State(), [])
  const onLoaded = action((widgets) => {
    state.widgets = widgets
    state.status = 'loaded'
  })
  const onClose = action((widget) => widget.status = 'animatingOut')
  
  if(state.hasActiveWidgets()){ // this causes rerender, whenever this function result changes (if state was changed inside action or runInAction)
    // something
  }

  ...
})
```

Also, you can put mobx state into react context and share it with multiple components. This way it could work similar to redux store.

Comment: You regular example has `const onLoaded = action((widgets) => {`

Comment: A mistake, fixed.

Comment: how does `onClose` interact with `State`?